# Get difference between two version of delta lake table

Tags: scala, apache-spark, delta-lake

how to find the difference between two last versions of a Delta Table ?
Here is as far as I went using dataframes :

```
val df1 = spark.read
  .format("delta")
  .option("versionAsOf", "0001")
  .load("/path/to/my/table")

val df2 = spark.read
  .format("delta")
  .option("versionAsOf", "0002")
  .load("/path/to/my/table")

// non idiomatic way to do it ...
df1.unionAll(df2).except(df1.intersect(df2))
```

there is a commercial version of Delta [by Databricks that provides a solution called CDF](https://databricks.com/blog/2021/06/09/how-to-simplify-cdc-with-delta-lakes-change-data-feed.html) but I'm looking for an open source alternative

Comment: looking for this one? https://kb.databricks.com/delta/compare-versions-delta-table.html

Comment: does loading the list of parquet files in a dataframe gives the exact difference between two version ?

Comment: theoretically, the difference is only between the two time sanpshots, so if you get the corresponding parquet files you get the difference. plus that is official doc so I guess it does what you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the comment of @Zinking, I managed to get a Dataframe with the difference being calculated between two versions :

**1) get the latest version :**

```
val lastVersion = DeltaTable.forPath(spark, PATH_TO_DELTA_TABLE)
    .history()
    .select(col("version"))
    .collect.toList
    .headOption
    .getOrElse(throw new Exception("Is this table empty ?"))
```

**2) get the list of parquet files flagged as to be "added" or "removed"** in a specific version `0000NUMVERSION` :

```
val addPathList = spark
    .read
    .json(s"ROOT_PATH/_delta_log/0000NUMVERSION.json")
    .where(s"add is not null")
    .select(s"add.path")
    .collect()
    .map(path => formatPath(path.toString))
    .toList
val removePathList = spark
    .read
    .json(s"ROOT_PATH/_delta_log/0000NUMVERSION.json")
    .where(s"remove is not null")
    .select(s"remove.path")
    .collect()
    .map(path => formatPath(path.toString))
    .toList
```

**3) load them in a dataframe**

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val addDF = spark
  .read
  .format("parquet")
  .load(addPathList: _*)
  .withColumn("add_remove", lit("add"))
val removeDF = spark
  .read
  .format("parquet")
  .load(removePathList: _*)
  .withColumn("add_remove", lit("remove"))
```

**4) the union of both dataframes represents the "diff":**

```
addDF.union(removeDF).show()


+----------+----------+
|updatedate|add_remove|
+----------+----------+
|      null|       add|
|      null|       add|
|      null|       add|
|      null|       add|
|      null|       add|
|      null|       add|
|      null|       add|
|      null|       add|
|      null|       add|
|      null|       add|
|      null|       add|
|      null|       add|
|      null|       add|
|      null|       add|
|      null|       add|
|      null|       add|
|      null|       add|
|      null|       add|
|      null|       add|
|      null|       add|
+----------+----------+
only showing top 20 rows
```

Answer (score 1):

This return a data frame with the comparative

```
import uk.co.gresearch.spark.diff.DatasetDiff

df1.diff(df2)
```